# How to overwrite css using different classes without !important

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

In my code I have a generic form for all my button:

```
input[type="button"],put[type="button"]:active,input[type="button"]:hover {
    width: 172px;
    height: 37px;
    line-height: 2 !important;
    margin: 11px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px 150px 9px 5px;
    line-height: 19px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

But some buttons in the system are half or a third the width of the generic buttons. And so they are still type button and receive the css above but I want to change only the width and have it look something like this without using !important.

```
.thirdButton, .thirdButton:active {
    width: 28px;
    padding: 0;
    background-position-x: 50%;
}
```

Comment: You should add another class to them or use another attribute they have so they have a higher *specificity*, like: `.thirdButton.myClass, .thirdButton.myClass:active`

Comment: classes should be with higher specificity than general selectors

Comment: @DaemonPainter Not 'should be'; class selectors *are* higher specificity than general element selectors. However, *attribute* selectors are in the same specificity column as class selectors.

Comment: @Eduardo read this article https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add more specificity to your CSS, to very precisely target that type of element as well as increase the power of that selector. Like `input[type="button"].thirdButton{...}` see demo below:

```css
input[type="button"],
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="button"]:hover {
  width: 172px;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 2 !important;
  margin: 11px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 5px 150px 9px 5px;
  line-height: 19px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* this is the selector line to change */
input[type="button"].thirdButton, input[type="button"].thirdButton:hover,     
input[type="button"].thirdButton:active {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  background-position-x: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="generic" value="generic" /><br/>
<input type="button" name="third" value="third" class="thirdButton" />
```

Comment: This is a good answer. It can be even more specific like so: `input[type="button"].thirdButton`. Ultimately, the original code only needs a one line change where the `thirdButton` class is defined.

Comment: @camsnz you are absolutely correct! Feel free to make the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to edit the current class and change it to how you would like, create a new class if you want to keep the current class as it is

If you have a css class named the same, whatever is further down your page will take priority, IDs take priority over classes and !important takes priority over everything.

If you have 2 !importants, again, whatever is further down your page will take priority